# Link simbólico não funciona no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando tornar público uma pasta dentro do diretório *storage* do *Laravel*, porém não obtive sucesso. A pasta a ser tornada publica está no caminho:

```
project/storage/app/images
```

Sim, fora do *public*. Já tentei criar o *symblink* normalmente com:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

E até criou o *link* simbólico, mas ainda sim não obtive acesso as imagens.

Posteriormente tentei:

```
ls -l -s "project/storage/app/images" "project/public/"
```

Também sem sucesso.

Comment: Você pode fazer o redirecionamento via `.htaccess` ou configuração do *Nginx*. Caso utilize algum deles.

Comment: Não entendi como o htacess me ajudaria, visto que as imagens estão somente em /app/images/ , mas gostaria de saber como :) Obrigado pelo reply!

Comment: Se bem entendi, você quer acessar `https://www.example/storage/app/images` e ter acesso aos arquivos da pasta `/project/storage/app/images`. Caso seja isso, no *Nginx* e *Apache* você pode utilizar o [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Comment: Não, é que eu só posso exibir as imagens que estão em admin/public no Laravel e, como não é o caso, é necessario criar algo que permita tal coisa...

Comment: Teu ambiente é windows? Está usando algo como uma máquina Vagrant?

Comment: Ubuntu, não amigo.

Comment: Com o storage:link você cria o link símbolo e quando acessar vai ser storage/app/images/IMG.jpg. Tentou assim e mesmo assim ele não funcionou?? Não deu nenhum erro ao rodar o comando?!

Comment: Como você tá tentando acessar o arquivo público? Digo, por qual URI?

Comment: AnthonyRodrigues : não, tudo certo, até criou o ícone de link simbólico.



tropicoder12 : Com a seguinte URL: project.local/storage/public/images/image.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Quando você cria o link pro seu storage público, o acesso a ele passa a ser via `<host_do_projeto>/storage/<nome_do_arquivo>`, ou seja, se você fazer o upload de um arquivo para seu storage público como `foo.txt`, o acesso a ele será através de `<seu_host>/storage/foo.txt`, e a mesma coisa para arquivos em subpastas, como por exemplo `<seu_host>/storage/bar/foo.txt`. Você ainda pode usar a função `asset()` par gerar o link de acesso ao arquivo, por exemplo `echo asset('storage/foo.txt');`

Tente novamente, pelo `php artisan storage:link` criar o acesso ao diretório público, armazene seus arquivos de acesso público nele com as próprias funções do Laravel e acesse da forma como mencionei que é a forma correta de se usar essa forma de armazenamento.

Na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#introduction) tem tudo isso de forma mais detalhada e com outras formas de armazenamento.

Comment: Mas já o faço, da seguinte forma, por exemplo: project.local/storage/public/images/image.jpeg

Comment: E mesmo assim não funcionou? Esse caminho do arquivo "/public/images/image.jpeg" foi você quem definiu no momento do upload?

Comment: Posta na pergunta o código que faz o upload pra ver como o arquivo tá subindo.